# what does "our step family mash-up" mean?

Tags: meaning

in a movie, a girl describes her family new house as a place for her mother to write the next book, big enough for her and her brother and her step family mash-up. 
her mom is married a man who has two kids.

Comment: The girl's ***step family*** simply means the step-father and his children (her step-brothers and/or step-brothers). *Mash-up* is probably just a "creative, one-off" usage meaning ***mixture*** (of the different people from different *original* families, now combined into one new family).

Comment: As rhetorician says below, another, slightly older term for the same phenomenon is [_blended family_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blended%20family): "a family that includes children from a previous marriage of the wife, husband, or both parents." Merriam-Webster says that it dates to 1975.

Answer (score 6):

*[Mash-up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashup_%28music%29)* is a term meaning two songs that have been mixed together.  By analogy, the two families have been mixed together like remixed songs.

It's meant to sound trendy, like something a teenager would say.  It's not a term commonly used this way, but it would be easy for most native speakers to understand, particularly ones young enough to be familiar with audio mash-ups.

Answer (score 2):

When you say the word "mash," the average American probably thinks of "mashed potatoes," which are made from tender, boiled potatoes, milk, butter, and salt and pepper.

There is a kitchen tool called a potato masher ("smasher" in some places), which mashes all the ingredients together into a paste-like consistency.  Hence, a family mash-up would be an admixture of family members, which is also called, less colloquially, a "blended family."

Blended families are the result of divorce or the death of a spouse, followed by a re-marriage, with each spouse bringing his or her own children into the new, blended family.

This is probably more than you wanted or needed to know, but it may prove helpful to folks whose mother tongue isn't English.